# How to get an animation from XSI to XNA

Tags: xna

I have a basic animation in XSI working perfectly. Just two cubes one goes up ( frame 15 ) then down again ( frame 30 )so the entire animation is 30 frames long.

The problem is that I don't know how to export this model and see it in a XNA application. Google hunting didn't offer any enlightenment which is why I turn to you.

Thanks in advance! ( for any hint or example or guidance )

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write an Importer and maybe a Processor for the [XNA Content Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203887.aspx) because XSI is not supported by default. XNA use a special format (.xnb) and the purpose of the Content Pipeline is to convert any file format to .xnb format. It is quite a large topic if you are not familiar with content pipelines (like me !) so I suggest the link above and also [Shawn Hargreaves post on this subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnhar/archive/2008/11/24/content-pipeline-assemblies.aspx) with links to examples you can use.

Comment: Sorry it seems I was a bit ambiguous. I want to export from XSI to .fbx the animation and have it run in an xna project.

Comment: Oh sorry I thought XSI was the format and made no distinction between *model* and *animation*. I guess I can't help you on this one. My knowledge is very limited in this field :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [XSI Mod Tool](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/partners) ? That should allow you to export your model directly to your XNA project.

**EDIT:** Already posted this as a comment, but just in case you didn't see that here it is as part of my answer. [This page](http://blogs.msdn.com/dawate/archive/2008/02/05/building-a-3d-game-in-xna-from-scratch-free-video-tutorial-series-now-available.aspx) has a huge (video) tutorial on how to build, skin, rig and animate a model in XSI, and then use it in XNA. Although it targets XNA GS 2.0 the same principles should still apply.

Comment: Yes I'm using the mod tool. It does allow me to export, I think I tried getting a keyframe animation working without knowing anything about blending between fames. I'm pretty noob at this. I found KilloWatt, it worked for his samples ONLY.
I'm definitely doing something wrong :P it's just frustrating that is so easy to make something wrong instead of being easy to make something happen.

Comment: Hehe, I know how that feels. I have to admit I haven't played around with XSI myself, but I do know there's a good tutorial on how to use it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/dawate/archive/2008/02/05/building-a-3d-game-in-xna-from-scratch-free-video-tutorial-series-now-available.aspx Although it's a bit outdated (XNA GS 2.0) by now, but I'm sure the same principles still apply.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to export your model from XSI in a format that [Blender](http://www.blender.org) can understand (assuming you don't want to license a commercial package just for exporting some models) that also retains animation data. Then, from Blender, you can export to a format that XNA is more familiar with. It's a bit cumbersome, but it might work.